# Flutter URL strategy not woring on Web Release

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-navigation, flutter-release

Flutter web debug works fine when manually entering the url, and i am using "pathUrlStrategy" for example http://localhost:14143/secondPage.
But trying the same thing in release mode its just return 404 page for example http://localhost/secondPage when using xampp, github page, and when trying http://localhost/#/secondPage it redirects to home page http://localhost/home.

Comment: Are you using firebase hosting? If you did, make sure you didn't select "rewrite to home" during firebase init.

Comment: i am not using firebase hosting, tried in live python server on couldRun and xampp localhost

Answer (score 1):

When you run the built binary of your flutter-web in prod (e.g. on a python http server) you need to configure the web server to route your other paths to your flutter web's index.html.

See [Configuring your web server](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation/url-strategies#configuring-your-web-server) for more details.

Using python3 http server example script:

```
import http.server
import socketserver

class Handler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, directory=".", **kwargs)

    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/':
            self.path = '/index.html'
        elif self.path == '/home':
            self.path = '/index.html'
        elif self.path == '/secondPage':
            self.path = '/index.html'

        return http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)


with socketserver.TCPServer(("0.0.0.0", 8080), Handler) as httpd:
    print("web server running..")
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have improved upon this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71797969/17367031).

You can add the web folder, to the root of the file containing the `.py` script.
To do so, you'll have to run `flutter build web --release` within your flutter project. Then you'll be able to copy the web folder from `../build/web` to the other folder containing the `.py` file.

Change the directory argument in `__init__`, to the location of your web folder that was copied over.
Running the script and opening `localhost:8080` in your browser will then run your project build.

Note: The web folder can be any flutter build, form code magic, or from the project itself.

```
import http.server
import socketserver


class Handler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, directory="../script/web", **kwargs)

    paths = ["/", "/first-page", "/second-page"]

    def do_GET(self):
        if self.paths.__contains__(self.path):
            self.path = '/index.html'

        return http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)


with socketserver.TCPServer(("localhost", 8080), Handler) as httpd:
    print("web server running..")
    httpd.serve_forever()
```